# How to copy or drag n drop image from Webview2 to Canvas?

Tags: c#, uwp, webview2

From Webview2 I cannot drag anything in my C# UWP app, I have tried the DragStarting or any other event related to dragging, but none of them triggered.

I have also tried to copy the image from the webview2, but it does not add to the Clipboard history and nothing happens when I try to paste it on the canvas.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.